# Tkinter Multiple Image Viewer within Frame

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

I would like to make a window construction for a photo previewer. I am stuck. My code doesn't work.
I made a frame hierarchy shown below.
I would like to show thumbnails in the thumbnail frame.
[image]

```
# TODO 0: IMPORT REQUIRED LIBRARIES AND MODULES
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


# TODO 1: CREATE A CLASS
class EditScreen:
    def __init__(self, file_directory_list):
        self.edit_window_init()
        self.file_directory_list = file_directory_list
        self.display_selected_images()
        self.edit_window.mainloop()

# TODO 2: CREATE A NEW EDIT SCREEN
    def edit_window_init(self):
        self.edit_window = Toplevel()
        self.edit_window.title("Edit")
        self.edit_window.geometry('1200x800')
        self.background_color = "#F8F1F1"
        self.my_font_color = "#0A065D"
        self.my_font = 'Poppins'

# TODO 3: DISPLAY SELECTED IMAGES IN THIS SCREEN
    def display_selected_images(self):
        thumbnail_frame = Frame(self.edit_window, height=1200, width=300)
        thumbnail_frame.pack(side='left')
        thumbnail_frame_canvas= Canvas(master=thumbnail_frame)
        thumbnail_frame_canvas.place(x=0,y=0)
# TODO 3.1: PUT ALL SELECTED IMAGES THUMBNAIL TO LEFT HAND SIDE OF THE EDIT SCREEN
        for selected_image_directory in self.file_directory_list:
            print(self.file_directory_list.index(selected_image_directory))
            selected_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=selected_image_directory)
            selected_image_location = thumbnail_frame_canvas.create_image((30,30),image=selected_image)
            selected_image_location.pack()
            #.grid(row=self.file_directory_list.index(selected_image_directory),column=0)
```

Comment: This question is too vague, and maybe too broad. What does "doesn't work" mean? Does the program crash? Does it show the wrong images? Is the screen not appearing the way you want? Something else?

Comment: Hi Bryan, I admit that it is not written very clearly. I mean that I can't show the pictures on the thumbnail frame. I chose the pictures and got some different errors. I would like to know that general how can we show small pictures in a frame. If you also see any errors, please let me know.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Comment: @jasonharper Nope. Unfortunately...

Comment: Please show us the error you're getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider these lines of code:

```
selected_image_location = thumbnail_frame_canvas.create_image((30,30),image=selected_image)
selected_image_location.pack()
```

`create_image` is documented to return an integer, which is an internal id of the canvas object that was created. You then try to call `pack` on that integer, but integers don't have a `pack` method. You need to remove the call to `pack`

Another problem was mentioned in a comment to your question: [you're not saving a reference to the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function), so it's going to get destroyed by python's garbage collector.

You can save a reference by using a global list, and appending the images to that list:

```
def display_selected_images(self):
    global selected_images
    ...
    selected_images = []
    for selected_image_directory in self.file_directory_list:
        ...
        selected_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=selected_image_directory)
        selected_images.append(selected_image)
        ...
```